# ActionFilterAttribute mvc need to call One time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action, action-filter, actionfilterattribute

I have a scenario i need to check security for each menu item if  user 'A' is allowed to access this menu or not and for that reason i created a class which is inherited with ActionFilterAttribute

```
public class SecurityFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);
    }
}
```

and using this class on my controller

> ```
> [SecurityFilter]
> public class XYZController : Controller
> { 
>  public ActionResult Index() { 
>    return View(); 
>    } 
>  }
> ```

Now the problem is in my View i have @Html.Action() calls e.g

```
  @Html.Action("COM")
```

which results in calling onActionExecuting Method again, i Just want it to call it one time when menu link is clicked and for that method only where menu is redirecting not the other Action method which is render inside view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When called using `@Html.Action` the `IsChildAction` property of the `filterContext` will be true. You can rely on it to determine whether you actually want to do something or not:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
        return;

    Log("OnActionExecuting", filterContext.RouteData);
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you but I would like to rephrase my question can I get only those action results which creates url and not the Ajax calls and I'm using kendo panel for one action and that action is also returning false for IsChildAction

Comment: Invoking an action through Ajax call is not considered as a Child-Action because it is indeed a separate HTTP request. Anyway, if i understand you correctly, you basically want to be able to tell (inside `OnActionExecuting`) when the request is an Ajax request?

Comment: I just want to get those Acton which are clicked by client from menu and inside those action view there are other Acton calls from Ajax kendo panel and simple one which I don't want

Comment: So you basically want to tell whether it's an Ajax request or not?

Comment: Just check `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()`. Note that this is an Extension-Method.

Comment: i'm your fan brother :) everything works perfectly thank you once again